# Style to tab not applying

Tags: jquery, css, tabs

How do I apply a negative `margin-bottom` to an element dynamically when a link is clicked. Trying to remove the bottom border of a tab when it is clicked. when I applied a negative margin to the tab element it works but it's applied to all the tabs which looks funny. Can someone take a look?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
        var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');
 
        // Show/Hide Tabs
        jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();
 
        // Change/remove current tab to active
        jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
       // tried adding this code but it doesn't seem to work
        $(function() {
      $('tab-links a').click(function () {
          $( ".tab-links.active" ).css('margin-bottom','-2px');
      });
  });

 
        e.preventDefault();

    });
});
```

```css
/*----- Tabs -----*/
.tabs {
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
}
 
    /*----- Tab Links -----*/
    /* Clearfix */
    .tab-links:after {
        display:block;
        clear:both;
        content:'';
        margin-bottom: -18px;
    }
 
    .tab-links li {
        margin:0px 5px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        float:left;
        list-style:none;
        border-radius:3px 3px 0px 0px;
        border: 2px solid black;
        margin-bottom: -2px;
        
        

    }
    .tab-links li.active {
        border-bottom: none;
        /*margin-bottom: -2px;  tried declaring a margin here but it didn't work */
      
    }
 
        .tab-links a {
            padding:10px 15px;
            display:inline-block;
            border-radius:3px 3px 0px 0px;
            background:#7FB5DA;
            font-size:16px;
            font-weight:600;
            color:#4c4c4c;
            transition:all linear 0.15s;
           
            
        }
 
        .tab-links a:hover {
            background:#a7cce5;
            text-decoration:none;
        }

    li.active a {
        background:#fff;
        color:#4c4c4c;
        border-bottom: none;     
    }
    li.active a {
        border-bottom: none;
    }
    /*----- Content of Tabs -----*/
    .tab-content {
        padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
        border-radius:3px;
        box-shadow:-1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
        background:#fff;
        border: 2px solid black;
        

    }
 
        .tab {
            display:none;
        }
 
        .tab.active {
            display:block;
        }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="tabs">
        <ul class="tab-links">
            <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Tab #1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab2">Tab #2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab3">Tab #3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab4">Tab #4</a></li>
        </ul>   
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="tab1" class="tab active">
                <p>Tab #1 content goes here!</p>
                <p>Donec pulvinar neque sed semper lacinia. Curabitur lacinia ullamcorper nibh; quis imperdiet velit eleifend ac. Donec blandit mauris eget aliquet lacinia! Donec pulvinar massa interdum risus ornare mollis.</p>
            </div>
     
            <div id="tab2" class="tab">
                <p>Tab #2 content goes here!</p>
                <p>Donec pulvinar neque sed semper lacinia. Curabitur lacinia ullamcorper nibh; quis imperdiet velit eleifend ac. Donec blandit mauris eget aliquet lacinia! Donec pulvinar massa interdum risus ornare mollis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut euismod tempus hendrerit. Morbi ut adipiscing nisi. Etiam rutrum sodales gravida! Aliquam tellus orci, iaculis vel.</p>
            </div>
     
            <div id="tab3" class="tab">
                <p>Tab #3 content goes here!</p>
                <p>Donec pulvinar neque sed semper lacinia. Curabitur lacinia ullamcorper nibh; quis imperdiet velit eleifend ac. Donec blandit mauris eget aliquet lacinia! Donec pulvinar massa interdum ri.</p>
            </div>
     
            <div id="tab4" class="tab">
                <p>Tab #4 content goes here!</p>
                <p>Donec pulvinar neque sed semper lacinia. Curabitur lacinia ullamcorper nibh; quis imperdiet velit eleifend ac. Donec blandit mauris eget aliquet lacinia! Donec pulvinar massa interdum risus ornare mollis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut euismod tempus hendrerit. Morbi ut adipiscing nisi. Etiam rutrum sodales gravida! Aliquam tellus orci, iaculis vel.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"> </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using toggleClass instead like this:

JS:

```
$( ".tab-links a" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).toggleClass( "neq-margin" );
});
```

CSS:

```
.neq-margin  {
  margin-bottom: -2px;
}
```